# Handling error codes for with Firebase SDK

Tags: firebase, go, error-code

I am using `"firebase.google.com/go/messaging"` to send android notifications. I want to read out the error code of the response returned. It seems like the Go libs don't expose it. Is there a way I can achieve this?

```
res, err := f.client.Send(ctx, m.Message)
```

This is the function I am calling : https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-go/blob/master/messaging/messaging.go#L699-L704

Comment: The messaging package provides the IsXXX functions to check for specific errors ([example](https://godoc.org/firebase.google.com/go/messaging#IsMismatchedCredential)).  If those don't give you want you need, then use the reflect package to get the [error code](https://godoc.org/firebase.google.com/go/internal#FirebaseError.Code).

Comment: `err.Error()` will give you the error as a string, based on [this function](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-go/blob/master/messaging/messaging.go#L855-L881) in that lib it looks like the error code should be present in the literal error text so you could probably just get away with parsing the result of `err.Error()`